# how to store the images in the database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Here is my website made by the framework "CodeIgniter" and with a database that I created

[my personal website](http://www.littlecode.ymcdesign.com)

if you click an image on the wall in the first page, you'll enter in this category to see all the images, you can see that some images are unable to display, that's because when I made the database, I put all the images on my facebook profile, copy every image's url into the database, then display them by php with a "foreach", but facebook change their urls from time to time, that makes the url no longer link to the image.

I have already tried to take the image's url from my Google drive, it's worse, so it's not a stable way to store many images(200+) by borrowing the third part url, can somebody tell me the correct and stable way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can google there are lots of tutorial for storing image /img path in database detailed explanation can't be available here...:) hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement it is a better idea to store the images in a file system (Better Caching (Both server & Client) | Reduce Load on Database) and saving lot on user bandwidth (Returning users) and save the corresponding file path in the database. But you have to handle caching gracefully. Do consider Amazon web service S3 storage service.

For further reference: Here is the code snippet from [Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html) documentation.

Regards,
HBK

Comment: Hi, I guess the way that save the corresponding file path in the database will be goood, but how? I put all the images in a folder calls "all img", and then upload it to the server, but I don't know how to save the file path in the database, it's not like in the html, the 'src' in img tag.

Comment: @JiangLan In the reference its mentioned how to work with the file upload.  Can you provide more information on the Model/Table you have created?

Answer (score 0):

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `app_files` (
  `file_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `file_data` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Saving an image to model:

```
if(!empty($_FILES["company_logo"]) && $_FILES["company_logo"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && !is_on_demo_host())
{
    $allowed_extensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["company_logo"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if (in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions))
    {
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $_FILES["company_logo"]["tmp_name"];
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']     = 170;
        $config['height']   = 60;
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $company_logo = $this->Appfile->save($_FILES["company_logo"]["name"], file_get_contents($_FILES["company_logo"]["tmp_name"]), $this->config->item('company_logo'));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Appfile extends CI_Model 
{       
    function get($file_id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('app_files', array('file_id' => $file_id), 1);

        if($query->num_rows()==1)
        {
            return $query->row();
        }

        return "";

    }

    function save($file_name,$file_data, $file_id = false)
    {
        $file_data=array(
        'file_name'=>$file_name,
        'file_data'=>$file_data
        );

        if (!$file_id)
        {
            if ($this->db->insert('app_files',$file_data))
            {
                return $this->db->insert_id();
            }

            return false;
        }

        $this->db->where('file_id', $file_id);
        if ($this->db->update('app_files',$file_data))
        {
            return $file_id;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function delete($file_id)
    {
        return $this->db->delete('app_files', array('file_id' => $file_id)); 
    }
}

?>
```

Viewing image:

```
    $file = $this->Appfile->get($file_id);
    header("Content-type: ".get_mime_by_extension($file->file_name));
    echo $file->file_data;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a beginner of web develop, I don't unnderstand your answer, could you please give me more explain, such as where to write what, thanks

Comment: If you can't understand that example, I'd recommend you go back to PHP 101.

Comment: I am not sure how I could explain it better. You need to create a model `Appfile` in application/models. Create the database table and then put the code for saving and viewing an image in the controller you want to do this from.